# Python Tkinter: ¿Como puedo mover las posiciones x e y de una ventana?

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero hacer que una ventana al crearse se posicione en una posicion especifica, pero no se como hacer eso, intente haciendo esto pero no funciono

```
x = 1000
y = 1000
window.geometry(f'+{x.x_root}+{y.y_root}') # window es la variable de la ventana por cierto
```

No funciona, me dice que el entero no es valido ¿Que hago?

Saludos.

Comment: Los enteros no tienen ni un método `x_root` ni `y_root`. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Mover la ventana a una posicion en especifico

Comment: Es que el código es inválido. Así que quisiera saber si tienes en mente algo en concreto. Es decir, provee más detalles.

Comment: No, no tengo idea de como hacerlo, este codigo es reutilizado de otra ventana, que al detectar el movimiento del mouse un Frame se moveria, y en teoria con eso funcionaria

Comment: ¿`x` y `y` eran otra cosa antes? Por que con enteros no se puede hacer lo que dices.

Comment: x e y eran el e evento del mouse, yo hice un window.bind("<B1-Motion>", evento) y funcionaba

Comment: Geometry te permite definir el tamaño y la posición de la ventana. La sintaxis es "{ancho}x{alto}+{x}+{y}". También acepta las sintaxis "{ancho}x{alto}" y "+{x}+{y}" (esta ultima es la que necesitas usar)

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias! Ya funciono! :D

Answer (score 2):

**Solucion**

Por parte de los comentarios:

Lo que pasaba es que las variables `x` e `y` eran enteros, y los enteros no tienen los metodos `x_root, y_root`, la solucion era hacer esto:

```
x = 170
y = 50
window.geometry("150x150+" + str(x) + "+" + str(y)) // 150x150+170+50
```

El `"150x150"` es el tamaño, y la parte de `+ str(x) + "+" + str(y)` es la posicion en la pantalla en la que va a estar

Saludos.

Comment: [Los enteros si tienen métodos](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types). Lo que pasa es que los enteros no tienen los métodos root_x ni root_y. Por lo demás, buena respuesta!

Comment: Es verdad, ya lo corregí gracias!